# Not able to access REST controllers in Spring Securtiy even when the role matches

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-rest

WebSecurityConfig class is as follows:-

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {



    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/get*").hasAnyRole();


    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user1").password("user1Pass")
                .authorities("USER");
                //.and().withUser("admin").password("adminPass")
                //.authorities("ADMIN");
    }


    /*@Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
                .withUser("test").password("test123").roles("USER").and().
                withUser("test1").password("test123").roles("ADMIN");
    }

}*/
    }
```

Below is the REST controller:-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getprofessors", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Professor> getProfessors() {

        //return service.findProfessors();

        List<Professor> Professors = professorRepo.findAll();

        return  Professors;

    }
```

Below image represents the POSTMAN call I'm making:-

[image: Postman call I'm trying to make]

Getting 403 error when accessing this controller even when no role specification has been provided.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked other methods for antMatchers()? I mean permitAll() and others. Maybe problem with hasAnyRole(), because it takes String[ ] . It is empty maybe problem occurs because of that.

Comment: With permitAll(), it is working without any authentication. Have tried http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/get*").hasAnyRole("USER"); but still the endpoint isn't authorizing.

Comment: I have faced this kind of situation when i was used sts ide, but i have typed the same code in intellij idea it worked successfully.